# Specific Wasserstein distance on $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: optimal-transport, wasserstein

Consider the $W^2$ Wasserstein distance on $\Bbb{R}^2$, which we take with its Euclidean metric.

Given a probability measure $p$ on $\Bbb{R}$, consider the following two couplings of $p$ with itself:

- The identity coupling $\mathrm{id}_p$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$, supported entirely on the diagonal {$(x,x):x\in\Bbb{R}$};
- The product coupling $p\otimes p$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Is there an easy way to calculate, as measures on $\Bbb{R}^2$, the $W^2$ distance between $\mathrm{id}_p$ and $p\otimes p$?

Comment: Do you have any idea how the set of couplings $\Pi(\operatorname{id}_p,p\otimes p)$ looks like?

Comment: Not really, except that it's supported on a partial diagonal.

Comment: Did you look at the dual, i.e. try to figure out the potentials? Same direction: There is the characterization by Brennier (for the case where $p$ has a density).

Comment: But if all couplings are supported on the diagonal - then $W$ should be zero, no?